# I have send value in hidden input and see it also on that page but I’m getting null value in next servlet page Getting category from previous page

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

JSP:

```
 categoryId--><input type="hidden" name="categoryAddNews" value='<%=categoryId %>'>
 blogId--><input type="hidden" name="blogAddNews" value='<%=blogId %>'>
```

Java:

```
String blogAddNews = request.getParameter("blogAddNews");
String categoryAddNews = request.getParameter("categoryAddNews");
```

Comment: The code and message are not clear at all, show us the problem the functions we can help

Comment: Please edit the question properly in order to receive a proper answer.

Comment: Your snippet missing relevant code, can you add the HTML form code and the Java method that handles the request?

Comment: ok i will add the html and also the servlet code

Comment: <%
String categoryId = request.getParameter("CategoryId");
String blogId = request.getParameter("BlogId");
%><form action="UploadNewsImage" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="text"  name="NewsName">
<input type="text" name="NewsDescription">
<input type="file" name="NewsImage">
input type="submit" value="Add News">
categoryId--><input type="hidden"  name="category1" value='<%=categoryId %>'>
blogId--><input type="hidden" name="blog1" value='<%=blogId %>'>
</form>

Comment: PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 response.setContentType("text/jpg");
 String categoryAddNews = request.getParameter("category1");
 String blogAddNews = request.getParameter("blog1");
 String newsName = request.getParameter("NewsName");
 String newsDescription = request.getParameter("NewsDescription");

 out.print("categoryId==>"+categoryAddNews);
 out.print("------blogId==>"+blogAddNews);
 out.print("------newsName==>"+newsName);
 out.print("------newsDescription==>"+newsDescription);

Comment: this is the code

Answer (score 0):

Check few things

1. Verify if your page is submitted
2. Submit action is the servlet which has the above code
3. Your hidden field is in the submit form
4. Your hidden field is not shadowed by another field with same name

Comment: yes the page is submitted properly and the hidden fields are in form tag not outside and also names are different.. i will post screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest to drop the type="hidden" and do the following instead:

```
style="display:none;"
```

It has same effect in terms of visibility, but... type="hidden" is something which can cause some problems like you're having, and even if it isn't the case, better to use the style technique.

So in your case it will be:

```
<input style="display:none;" name="blogAddNews" value='<%=blogId %>'>
```

Comment: i don't know why its not solved yet by using style tag.. actually its not getting value in AddNews.jsp page itself..if any library is needed or resultsets name are different for every resultset ??

Comment: need to see rest of code to try and understand better

Comment: im getting values from previous page in only 1 .jsp page later on im not getting any value from any page ...why ??

Comment: <% String categoryId = request.getParameter("CategoryId"); String blogId = request.getParameter("BlogId"); %><form action="UploadNewsImage" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'> <input type="text" name="NewsName"> <input type="text" name="NewsDescription"> <input type="file" name="NewsImage"> input type="submit" value="Add News"> categoryId--><input type="hidden" name="category1" value='<%=categoryId %>'> blogId--><input type="hidden" name="blog1" value='<%=blogId %>'> </form>

Comment: PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 response.setContentType("text/jpg");
 String categoryAddNews = request.getParameter("category1");
 String blogAddNews = request.getParameter("blog1");
 String newsName = request.getParameter("NewsName");
 String newsDescription = request.getParameter("NewsDescription");

 out.print("categoryId==>"+categoryAddNews);
 out.print("------blogId==>"+blogAddNews);
 out.print("------newsName==>"+newsName);
 out.print("------newsDescription==>"+newsDescription);